# value for list.index(value) for index value 16 is set to 9

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a list

```
array_list=[-37, -36, -19, -99, 29, 20, 3, -7, -64, 84, 36, 62, 26, -76, 55, -24, 84, 49, -65, 41]
```

when i try to iterate through printing index and value associated to the index using below code

```
for value in array_list:
    print(array_list.index(value), array_list[array_list.index(value)])
```

I'm getting the below output:

```
0 -37
1 -36
2 -19
3 -99
4 29
5 20
6 3
7 -7
8 -64
9 84
10 36
11 62
12 26
13 -76
14 55
15 -24
9 84   # I want the value as 16 instead of 9 (position of 84 in list)
17 49
18 -65
19 41
```

At index 16 it is giving me value for index as 9.
I am not sure why as it should be giving me 16 as the index value.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can any one suggest why it is behaving like this?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the documentation on `list.index` can.

Comment: Index returns the index of the first instance of the value.

Comment: Because `84` is in your list multiple times, and `.index()` gives you the first location.  If you want to iterate over the keys/values, use `enumerate()`: `for key, value in enumerate(array_list):`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking it for the index of the first entry with that value (and then using that index). If you want the index at which the iteration (for loop) found it, try `for i,value in enumerate(array_list)`. Iterating over a list yields the items it contains, not something referring back to the list.

Answer (score 4):

`list.index(..)` returns the value of first occurrence of element in `list`. For example:

```
>>> my_list = [1,2,3,1,2,5]
>>> [(i, my_list.index(i)) for i in my_list]
[(1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2), (1, 0), (2, 1), (5, 5)]

# Here, 0th index element is the number
#       1st index element is the first occurrence of number
```

If you want to get the position of the element during the iteration, you should be using [**`enumerate`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) for iteration. For example:

```
>>> [(i, n) for n, i in enumerate(my_list)]
[(1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4), (5, 5)]

# Here, 0th index element is the number
#       1st index element is the position in the list
```

---

You may refer [Python's List Document](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), which says:

> **list.index(x)**
>
> Return the index in the list of the first item whose value is x. It is an error if there is no such item.